# Invoice template changes not showing

Tags: invoice, pdf, magento-1.5

I have changed my invoice template to add some footer text, this works fine.  However recently I have been asked to change this text to correct a typo.  This I have done but the change is not showing on the invoice, it still shows the old text with the typo.

I have cleared and disabled my caches but to no avail.

The file I am changing is located at `\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php`

Does anyone know as to why the changes are not showing?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Always worth checking after any magento changes.

Comment: Maybe the typo is made in locale translation files and not in modified core .php file placed in local?

Comment: Hi, I have cleared all caches both through admin and manually.

Comment: Arent template files phtml? Not php?

Comment: Invoice.php is the correct file as the original text shows.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet? If not, maybe the method (or class) has a rewrite from another extension which has the typo?